# MySQL query to count cumulative user number based on activation date groupped by month

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, window-functions, recursive-query

I have following table and data:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_users (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `activation_date` DATETIME
  );

INSERT INTO tbl_users (id, activation_date) VALUES
    (1, '2020-01-15' ),
    (2, '2020-02-13' ),
    (3, '2020-02-15' ),
    (4, '2020-03-01' ),
    (5, '2020-03-03' ),
    (6, '2020-05-01' ),
    (7, '2020-06-01' ),
    (8, '2020-07-15' ),
    (9, '2020-08-15' ),
    (10, '2020-08-15' ),
    (11, '2020-08-19' );
```

I am looking for optimal way to count summary number of the users at the end of each month based on the activation date. for test data above output should look like below:

```
month   cumulative
1       1
2       3
3       5
4       5
5       6
6       7
7       8
8       11
9       11
10      11
```

I was trying with:

```
SELECT MONTH(activation_date) as month, COUNT(*) as cumulative 
FROM tbl_users 
WHERE activation_date >= :start GROUP BY month
```

but I get values for specific months instead of cumulative.
Any idea how to improve the query?
Or do I need to process it later in php?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for 'an optimal way', or just 'a way'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since MySQL 8.0 you can use window function for this task:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    MONTH(activation_date) as month, 
    SUM(1) over (order by MONTH(activation_date) )as cumulative 
FROM tbl_users 
WHERE activation_date >= :start 
;
```

[SQL editor online](https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql80/a9f58018303a893afccf53f0451060d3/)

**Result:**

```
+-------+------------+
| month | cumulative |
+-------+------------+
|     1 |          1 |
|     2 |          3 |
|     3 |          5 |
|     5 |          6 |
|     6 |          7 |
|     7 |          8 |
|     8 |         11 |
+-------+------------+
```

Comment: This fails to generate a row for months when no user was activated, eg April.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you could use a recursive query to generate the months, then bring the table with a `left join`, and finally compute the cumulative sum:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select 
        date_format(min(activation_date), '%Y-%m-01') dt,
        date_format(max(activation_date), '%Y-%m-01') max_dt
    from tbl_users
    union all
    select dt + interval 1 month, max_dt
    from cte
    where dt < max_dt
)
select c.dt, sum(count(u.id)) over(order by dt) cumulative
from cte c
left join tbl_users u
    on  u.activation_date >= c.dt
    and u.activation_date <  c.dt + interval 1 month
group by c.dt
order by c.dt
```

Note that this generates the lower and upper bound of the date range directly from the available dates in the table, which seems more sensible than using a fixed range.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a0281bc28a4639d67c4e7bf6219f3b57)**:

```
dt         | cumulative
:--------- | ---------:
2020-01-01 |          1
2020-02-01 |          3
2020-03-01 |          5
2020-04-01 |          5
2020-05-01 |          6
2020-06-01 |          7
2020-07-01 |          8
2020-08-01 |         11
```

Comment: Just a pragmatic question: for large tables (several k rows) and rather often queries would it be recommended to complicate the query or rather go only for month values and sum it up when retrieving the data  to the PHP array? Will impact of this recursive operation be significant on the database? Thanks!